# coloring the skipped mandatory field using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a aspx form with few mandatory fields. I've applied the same style for all those fields say `txtbxrequired`. I want to color all those skipped mandatory fields to yellow. How to achieve that. Below is the code I'm using but it colors even the filled fields:

```
if ($(".txtbxrequired").val() == "") {
    $(".txtbxrequired").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks dudes, I've found a answer $(".txtbxrequired").each(function () {
       if($(this).val() =="")
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow") ;                });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.txtbxrequired').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).val();
}).css('background-color', 'yellow');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/FAs6W/

Your code doesn't work because you explicitly set yellow color to *all* elements that has class `txtbxrequired`.

What my code does is - selects all the elements with `txtbxrequired` class, then filters only ones, that doesn't have any value, and sets the background color for them

Comment: Any idea what the performance difference is (if any) between using `filter` versus using `each`?

Comment: @djlumley: probably not significant, but I don't know (in this particular case I tried just to have something readable and easy to understand)